# $(window).scrollTop() Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions. The first checks whether an element is within view as the page is scrolled. The second one is meant to calculate the scroll top and if the first function is true, that is when the element is in view, it sets the scrollTop of that element to 0.

My solution to get this done was to start a separate counter that is only activated when the element is in view, but I am having trouble making a working counter. As it is now, the value of `i` is stuck at `1`. Below is my code, any input is appreciated.

```js
var img = $('.banner_img_desktop').find('img');

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var i = 0; // <-- my counter
  if (isScrolledIntoView(img)) {
    i = i + 1;
    var elemScroll = i;
    var imgPos = (elemScroll / 8) + 'px';
    img.css('transform', 'translateY(' + imgPos + ')');
  }
});
```

Comment: I think that happens because the scope of variable `i` is local to the scroll function. If you want to use it as `global`, declare it outside the `scroll` function.

Comment: hey @kontenurban do you plan to fix the position of image or something similar when user scroll into viewport? if that is the case then do not make any counter based on SCROLL event (it's not constant and can do more damage to code) it's better to set custom CSS class when upper function is TRUE!

Comment: @KresimirPendic Yes i do, I am actually trying to get a parallax effect! As I have it now, if there is a lot of content on the page, the img inside the container disappears because by the time one reaches the element the value of scroll is very high, hence also the transform: translateY(). Thus, my idea of only starting to count those values when the element is in view!

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: @kontenurban you're welcome, please self-answer your question :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @GrafiCode Studios's advice! The scope of the variable `i` was local to the `scroll` function and I wanted to use it as global! The solution was to  declare it outside the `scroll` function!